# reading large dask.array h5py from spinning disk

Tags: python, performance, dask

saw Matthew Rocklin's awesome pycon 2017 talk about dask and immediately had to start playing with it.

I'm working on hyperspectral recordings. Total dataset size is about 1-3 TB, each individual recording/image I want to analyze is about 12 GB, and is split across 2000 MB files (usually 7 per recording). I've concatenated the arrays into one `dask.array` using `da.concatenate` of several `da.from_array` called on h5py datasets. I notice that CPU usage is low and IO performance is poor; disk read speeds is about 15-30 MB/s on my system monitor. Experience indicates about 250 MB/s as max read/write speed on this disk (2x 6 TB HDD in RAID-0).

Gut feeling tells me the issue is that many threads are reading the 7 files in question (I'm guessing 24 as that's my hyperthread count), meaning that disk seeks are thrashing my IO performance. How can I get an overview over what Dask is doing and prevent those seeks?

Versions and hardware: Ubuntu 16.04, anaconda python 3.5, dask 0.15.1 (most recent version in conda). 2xhexa-core Intel Xeon CPU (24 hyperthreads total), 80 GB RAM, 2 HDDs in RAID-0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Locking to avoid thrashing disk

Your hypothesis that multiple concurrent reads are thrashing your disk seems sensible to me.  To test this you might play with the `lock=` keyword argument to [da.from_array](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_array)

Passing `True` to this keyword creates a lock for all access for that call.  This would help a little bit but wouldn't control access between from_array calls.  You can also create an explicit lock and pass that in directly.  This will restrict all of your data access to be constrained to only call one at a time.

from threading import Lock
lock = Lock()

arrays = [da.from_array(inp, lock=lock, chunks=...) for inp in inputs]

#### Align chunks with HDF5

You should also ensure that how you pull data out of HDF5 is well aligned with how HDF5 is storing your data.  Not having these two be well aligned can easily destroy I/O bandwidth.  For example if your HDF5 files are not chunked at all then they are probably stored in C-order.  In this case you would want to ensure that you are not breaking up the latter indices at all when chunking.

Comment: I've noticed that using `lock=True` works with `dask.distributed` but `lock=threading.Lock()` does not, as it cannot be pickled. The chunking was great advice though, the hdf5 files are chunked so it seems a bit of tweaking there helps a great deal. The data are always chunked with small chunk sizes in the first dimension, so should be easy enough to do something adaptive there.

Comment: For distributed locks see `dask.utils.SerializableLock`